# Grouping and Sum of XML nodes using xslt

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I am pretty new in XSLT and I am stuck at once place.

I have one input xml file as below

```
<Roots>
    <Root>
        <Value1>Links1</Value1>
        <Value2>notadmin</Value2>
        <Count>1</Count>
    </Root>
    <Root>
        <Value1>Links1</Value1>
        <Value2>notadmin</Value2>
        <Count>10</Count>
    </Root>
    <Root>
        <Value1>Links2</Value1>
        <Value2>userxyz</Value2>
        <Count>10</Count>
    </Root>
    <Root>
        <Value1>Links2</Value1>
        <Value2>usermnp</Value2>
        <Count>10</Count>
    </Root>
    <Root>
        <Value1>Links3</Value1>
        <Value2>user123</Value2>
        <Count>5</Count>
    </Root>
    ...
            ...
            ...
</Roots>
```

Now, I want to sum the count value for similar values of Value1 and Value2 so that it looks like below:

```
<Roots>
    <Root>
        <Value1>Links1</Value1>
        <Value2>notadmin</Value2>
        <Count>11</Count>
    </Root>

    <Root>
        <Value1>Links2</Value1>
        <Value2>userxyz</Value2>
        <Count>20</Count>
    </Root>

    <Root>
        <Value1>Links3</Value1>
        <Value2>user123</Value2>
        <Count>5</Count>
    </Root>

</Roots>
```

I have been trying a lot to transform this xml and here is my code:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
exclude-result-prefixes="xs" >
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
<xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Roots">
<Roots>
<Root>
<xsl:for-each-group select="Root" group-by=
    "concat(Value1, '+', Value2)">
        <xsl:copy-of select=
    "current-group()[1]/*[starts-with(name(),'key')]"/>

    <Count>
        <xsl:value-of select="sum(current-group()/Count)"/>
    </Count>


</xsl:for-each-group>

    </Root>
</Roots>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I know I am doing wrong and could be lot easier to the expert but I really need some help and direction.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your XSLT was close, but move the `<Root>` element definition into the `xsl:for-each-group`. I couldn't make sense of your `xsl:copy-of...`, so I just reproduced the elements one-by-one. So use this simple XSLT-2.0 stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/Roots">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
            <xsl:for-each-group select="Root" group-by="Value1">
                <Root>
                    <Value1><xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()" /></Value1>
                    <Value2><xsl:value-of select="current-group()[1]/Value2" /></Value2>
                    <Count><xsl:value-of select="sum(current-group()/Count)" /></Count>
                </Root>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**It's output is:**

```
<Roots>
   <Root>
      <Value1>Links1</Value1>
      <Value2>notadmin</Value2>
      <Count>11</Count>
   </Root>
   <Root>
      <Value1>Links2</Value1>
      <Value2>userxyz</Value2>
      <Count>20</Count>
   </Root>
   <Root>
      <Value1>Links3</Value1>
      <Value2>user123</Value2>
      <Count>5</Count>
   </Root>
</Roots>
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now, your grouping `concat(Value1, '+', Value2)` will not yield three nodes since nodes at *Links2* maintains two different *value2* node values. Also, your identity transform template is redundant since you rewrite the XML tree directly from root, *Roots*.

**One Grouping** *(only Value1)*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="2.0" exclude-result-prefixes="xs">
   <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />

   <xsl:template match="Roots">
      <Roots>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="Root" group-by="Value1">
            <Root>
                  <xsl:copy-of select="Value1|Value2"/>
                   <Count>
                      <xsl:value-of select="sum(current-group()/Count)" />
                   </Count>
            </Root>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
      </Roots>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Returns with first *value2* returned:

```
<Roots>
   <Root>
      <Value1>Links1</Value1>
      <Value2>notadmin</Value2>
      <Count>11</Count>
   </Root>
   <Root>
      <Value1>Links2</Value1>
      <Value2>userxyz</Value2>
      <Count>20</Count>
   </Root>
   <Root>
      <Value1>Links3</Value1>
      <Value2>user123</Value2>
      <Count>5</Count>
   </Root>
</Roots>
```

**Two Groupings** *(Value1 and Value2)*

Keeping original grouping:

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="Root" group-by="concat(Value1, '+', Value2)">
```

Returns four nodes

```
<Roots>
   <Root>
      <Value1>Links1</Value1>
      <Value2>notadmin</Value2>
      <Count>11</Count>
   </Root>
   <Root>
      <Value1>Links2</Value1>
      <Value2>userxyz</Value2>
      <Count>10</Count>
   </Root>
   <Root>
      <Value1>Links2</Value1>
      <Value2>usermnp</Value2>
      <Count>10</Count>
   </Root>
   <Root>
      <Value1>Links3</Value1>
      <Value2>user123</Value2>
      <Count>5</Count>
   </Root>
</Roots>
```